# Best practice to check if a process is running on Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, process, chef-infra

I installed chef server with the script below. I'm new to linux and I'm trying to learn how to set up chef server. I ran the commands chef.io provides and the script succeeded. I'm really not sure how to check or what I should do to check if the process is running.  What are the best practices for linux on how to see if a process is running? What are the things I could do to find out what I need to know?

```
        #!/bin/bash \
echo "Do your provisioning here" \
sudo wget https://packages.chef.io/files/stable/chef-server/12.14.0/el/7/chef-server-core-12.14.0-1.el7.x86_64.rpm \
sudo chmod a+x chef-server-core-12.14.0-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
sudo rpm -Uvh ./chef-server-core-12.14.0-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
sudo chef-server-ctl reconfigure \
sudo openssl rsa -in private.pem -outform PEM -pubout -out ~/.ssh/chef-server.pem \
sudo chef-server-ctl user-create admin 'admin' 'email' 'password' --filename ~/.ssh/chef-server.pem \
sudo openssl rsa -in private.pem -outform PEM -pubout -out ~/.ssh/chef-server-validator.pem \
sudo chef-server-ctl org-create short_name 'idevops' --association_user admin --filename ~/.ssh/chef-server-validator.pem \
sudo openssl rsa -in private.pem -outform PEM -pubout -out ~/.ssh/chef-coffee-server-validator.pem \
sudo chef-server-ctl org-create 4thcoffee 'iDevops 4th Coffee' --association_user admin --filename ~/.ssh/chef-coffee-server-validator.pem \
sudo chef-server-ctl install chef-manage \
sudo chef-server-ctl reconfigure \
sudo chef-manage-ctl reconfigure \
sudo chef-server-ctl install opscode-push-jobs-server \
sudo chef-server-ctl reconfigure \
sudo opscode-push-jobs-server-ctl reconfigure \
sudo chef-server-ctl install opscode-reporting \
sudo chef-server-ctl reconfigure \
sudo opscode-reporting-ctl reconfigure \
sudo chef-server-ctl install PACKAGE_NAME --path /path/to/package/directory \
sudo chef-server-ctl install chef-manage --path /root/packages \
sudo mkdir /etc/opscode && sudo touch /etc/opscode/chef-server.rb \
sudo echo "license['nodes'] = 0" >> /etc/opscode/chef-server.rb \
sudo chef-server-ctl reconfigure
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with chef, but for most servers you should be able to query them with some kind of request.

Comment: Probably stop doing this in a bash script and use the chef-ingredients cookbook instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a relatively LARGE hint in the output you posted (e.g. `chef-server-ctl status`),

> ```
> The status subcommand is used to show the status of all services available 
> to the Chef server. The results will vary based on the configuration of a 
> given server.
> ```

or, `chef-server-ctl status SERVICE_NAME`

> ```
> where SERVICE_NAME represents the name of any service that is listed after 
> running the service-list subcommand.
> ```

See Also the `start` subcommand at [**chef-server-ctl (executable)**](https://docs.chef.io/ctl_chef_server.html) (toward the bottom of the page)

Answer (score 2):

Ok, there is a few places you can find them online, first thing you want to do is check if the process is running.

ps aux | grep process_name

Then if it is running and you still can't access it. You will want to use the netstat command and grep for the port.

```
net stat -anp | grep portnumber
```

You look to see if the service is running on the port its supposed to be. It will say its listening. Listening means the port is looking for communication on that port. This will mean the application is up and looking for communication on the port, or the port is inuse by another app and thats why it didn't start.

generally you would then look in the lgos tail -f -n 100 /path/to/log/file
   -n is the number of lines
    -f is a continuous follow so its how you watch the file. If you don't specify it it will just cat 100 lines to the screen.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to check it manually, log into the server and run:

```
ps auxw | grep YOUR_PROCESS_NAME
```

Answer (score 1):

First, I do not run commands from a script until I know they work. 
You may not be running the service:

```
    sudo service chef-server status #would be a good place to start
```

To check if a process is running on linux I would recommend starting with the following:

```
    ps aux | grep <part of the process name>
    ps aux | grep chef
```

If you do not like the output of aux you can also use -ef like:

```
    ps -ef | grep <part of the process name>
    ps -ef | grep chef
```

If you know what port the process should be open on you could use netstat:

```
    netstat -anp | grep <port number>
```

Example: looking for nginx or apache server to be running:

```
    netstat -anp | grep 80
```

Watching logs I like to use the tail command:

```
    tail -f /var/log/<name of application folder/<name of log>
```

Example: watching nginx logs:

```
    tail -f /var/log/nginx/nginx.log
```

Sometimes it is helpful to watch the syslog as well:

```
    tail -f -n 100 /var/log/syslog
```

If looking for incoming connections from other machines:

```
    sudo tcpdump -vvv -i any port <port number>
```